# addOnScrollListener в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Странная ошибка, при добавлении слушателя в RecyclerView приложение вылетает вот с такими ошибками:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:2799)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2586)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2971)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:562)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2114)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Код внутрь заходит, даже что-то делает, но приложение все равно вылетает.

```
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            setToolbarAlpha(dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    });
```

UPD ошибка вылазит где то в этом блоке:

```
   private void setToolbarAlpha(int current) {
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mRecyclerView.getWidth(),
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    View listItem = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(0);
    listItem.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int firstItemHeigth = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    if (firstItemHeigth > 0) {
        float d = (float) Math.abs(current) / (float) firstItemHeigth;
        Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
        if (d < 1) {
            drawable.setAlpha((int) (d * 255));
        } else {
            drawable.setAlpha(255);
        }
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference

Ключевая фраза в тексте ошибки - NullPointerException.
[Хабрахабр: Как понять NullPointerException](http://habrahabr.ru/post/221243/)
[Stackoverflow: What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)